# How to build an xpath / css-selector based on relative value for Protractor

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver, protractor

I am trying to select one checkbox from multiple check boxes, and none of the checkbox has any unique identifier of any sort. The only way we can distinguish them at this point is to check the label of the check boxes. But the labels are put as a sibling in the html structure , which is as follows:

```
<div _ngcontent-c9="" class="row  pb-2">
<div _ngcontent-c9="" class="form-group col-10 pl-0 mb-0 d-flex justify-contents-center">
    <div _ngcontent-c9="" class="col-6">
        <label _ngcontent-c9="" class="col  ml-2"> Homebound Services: <br _ngcontent-c9="">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c9="" class="col-6 pl-0 ">
        <input _ngcontent-c9="" type="checkbox">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div _ngcontent-c9="" class="row  pb-2">
    <div _ngcontent-c9="" class="form-group col-10 pl-0 mb-0 d-flex justify-contents-center">
        <div _ngcontent-c9="" class="col-6">
            <label _ngcontent-c9="" class="col  ml-2"> Home-Based Services: 
            <br _ngcontent-c9="">
            </label>
        </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c9="" class="col-6 pl-0 ">
    <input _ngcontent-c9="" type="checkbox">
    </div>
</div>
```

From this snippet, I need to select the two check boxes which have labels "Homebound services" and Home-based Services" . Below is my failed attempt to build the dynamic xpath:

```
//div[@class="row  pb-2"]//label[contains(text()," Homebound ESY Services: ")] and //input[type="checkbox"]
```

How can I build this xpath? Also if we can build dynamic CssSelector for the same elements, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To identify the respective *check boxes* you can use the following solution:

- *XPath* for `Homebound Services`:

  ```
  "//label[contains(., 'Homebound Services:')]//following::input[1]"
  ```
- *XPath* for `Home-Based Services`:

  ```
  "//label[contains(., 'Home-Based Services:')]//following::input[1]"
  ```